# Recursive call return a List, return type causing me issues

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a recursive method that returns categories, and checks for its sub categories.

This is my code:

```cs
public List<Category> GetAllChildCats(int categoryid) 
{
    List<Category> list = new List<Category>();

    Category c = Get(categoryid);

    foreach(Category cat in c.ChildCategories) 
    {
        list.Add(GetAllChildCats(cat.CategoryID));
    }

}
```

This fails because the call to `list.Add()` expects a `Category` object, but `GetAllChildCats()` returns `List<Category>`

How should I work around this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Currently you haven't shown anything which actually adds a single category to the list... I'm assuming that as you recurse, you want to add the results of `Get(categoryId)` as well·

Preet's solution will certainly work, but here's an alternative which avoids creating all the extra lists:

```
public List<Category> GetAllChildCats(int categoryId)
{
    List<Category> ret = new List<Category>();
    GetAllChildCats(categoryId, ret);
    return ret;
}

private void GetAllChildCats(int categoryId, List<Category> list)
{
    Category c = Get(categoryid);
    list.Add(c);

    foreach(Category cat in c.ChildCategories)
    {
        GetAllChildCats(cat.CategoryID, list);
    }
}
```

This creates a single list, and adds items to it as it goes.

One point though - if you've already got the child `Category` objects, do you really need to  call `Get` again? Does each child only contain its ID until you fetch the whole category?

Answer (score 12):

```
   foreach(Category cat in c.ChildCategories)
      {
              list.AddRange( GetAllChildCats(cat.CategoryID) )

      }
```

**and don't forget the**

```
return list;
```

Comment: Currently that will always end up returning an empty list... see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I think this linq version will allow you to avoid the overhead of creating a list:

```
public IEnumerable<Category> GetAllChildCats(int categoryid)
{
    Category c = Get(categoryid);
    return new[] { c }.Concat(c.ChildCategories.SelectMany(cat => GetAllChildCats(cat)));
}
```

You can always call ToList() on the returned IEnumerable if you need it.

Comment: You are keen. .SelectMany for recursion is slow as hell.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem before. Here is the way I solved it:

```
public void GetAllChildCategories(ProductCategory ParentCategory)
{
    ParentCategory.ChildCategories = GetChildCategories(ParentCategory.ID);

    foreach(ProductCategory cat in ParentCategory.ChildCategories)
    {
        GetAllChildCategories(cat);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modified version of Jon Skeet's answer using a local method (C# 7) :

```
    public List<Category> GetAllChildCats(int rootId)
    {
        List<Category> list = new List<Category>();
        Traverse(rootId);
        return list;

        void Traverse(int categoryId)
        {
            Category c = Get(categoryId);
            list.Add(c);

            foreach (Category cat in c.ChildCategories)
            {
                Traverse(cat.CategoryID);
            }
        }
    }
```