# MVC4 bootstrap-treeview getting json data from database

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, treeview

I am using [Bootstrap-Treeview](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview)
.I want to get the json data in the following format from the server.

```js
 $("#tree").treeview({
   data: getTree(),
   levels: 6
 });


 function getTree() {

   var tree = [{
     text: "ED",
     icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
     nodes: [{
       text: "CPD",
       icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
       nodes: [{
         text: "Center Manager",
         icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
         nodes: [{
           text: "Manager",
           icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
           nodes: [{
             text: "Tech Head",
             icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
             nodes: [{
               text: "Individual",
               icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
             }]
           }]

         }]

       }]
     }]
   }];

   var jsonTree = JSON.stringify(tree);
   return jsonTree;
 };
```

The controller action method is as follows

```
  public ActionResult getJsonTree()
    {
        List<Role> _lstRole = _db.Roles.ToList();
        List<RoleVM> _lstViewRole = new List<RoleVM>();
        foreach(var _role in _lstRole)
        {
            if (_role.ChildID == null)
            {                   
                _lstViewRole=_db.Roles.Where(x=>x.Id==_role.Id).
                            Select(x=>new RoleVM(){
                            text=x.RoleName,
                            icon="glyphicon glyphicon-user"
                            }).ToList();

            }
            getChildNode(_role.Id, _lstViewRole);

        }
        var roles = _lstViewRole.ToArray();

        return Json(roles, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    private void getChildNode(int _roleId, List<RoleVM> _lstRole)
    {
        RoleVM _childNode = _db.Roles.Where(x => x.ChildID == _roleId).
                           Select(x => new RoleVM()
                           {
                               text = x.RoleName,
                               icon = "glyphicon glyphicon-user"
                           }).FirstOrDefault();
        _lstRole.Add(_childNode);

    }
```

The json format i get is as follows

```js
[

  {

    "text": "ED",
    "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
    "node": null

  }, {

    "text": "CPD",
    "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
    "node": null

  }, {

    "text": "Centre Manager",
    "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
    "node": null

  }, {

    "text": "Manager",
    "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
    "node": null

  }, {

    "text": "Tech Head",
    "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
    "node": null

  },

  {
    "text": "Individual",
    "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
    "node": null
  },
  null

]
```

How can I get the json format in the correct manner.Any Idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var roles = _db.Roles.Select(x => new { text = x.RoleName, icon = "glyphicon glyphicon-user" }).ToArray();
return Json(roles, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This will however not display child nodes.

You will need to build up a parent-child hierarchy but without seeing your data and how the roles relate, one can only guess!

I've used Newtonsoft.Json to perform the serialization, and you could too!
Given the following classes/code

```
public class RoleViewModel
    {

        public RoleViewModel()
        {
            this.ChildRoles = new List<RoleViewModel>();
        }

        public string text { get; set; }

        public string icon { get { return "glyphicon glyphicon-user"; } }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nodes")]
        public List<RoleViewModel> ChildRoles { get; set; }
    }
//mimic db call:
private static List<RoleViewModel> roles = new List<RoleViewModel>
            {
                new RoleViewModel { Id = 1, ParentId = null, text = "ED" },
                new RoleViewModel { Id = 2, ParentId = 1, text = "CPD" },
                new RoleViewModel { Id = 3, ParentId = 2 ,text = "Center Manager" },
                new RoleViewModel { Id = 4 , ParentId = 3, text = "Manager" },
                new RoleViewModel { Id = 5 , ParentId = 4, text = "Tech Head" },
                new RoleViewModel { Id = 6 , ParentId = 5, text = "Individual" }
            };
```

For the recursion:

```
public static RoleViewModel ChildrenOf(RoleViewModel role)
        {

            foreach (RoleViewModel child in roles.Where(x => x.ParentId == role.Id))
            {
                role.ChildRoles.Add(ChildrenOf(child));
            }

            return role;
        }
```

and for the conversion:

```
var role = ChildrenOf(roles[0]);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new[] { role });
```

Produces:

```
[
    {
        "text": "ED",
        "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
        "nodes": [
            {
                "text": "CPD",
                "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
                "nodes": [
                    {
                        "text": "Center Manager",
                        "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
                        "nodes": [
                            {
                                "text": "Manager",
                                "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
                                "nodes": [
                                    {
                                        "text": "Tech Head",
                                        "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
                                        "nodes": [
                                            {
                                                "text": "Individual",
                                                "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
                                                "nodes": []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Hi Ric Thanks for the response.There is 6 items in the database each having Rank1,Rank2,..Rank6. I want to show having item with Rank1 first,then the child of Rank1 will be Rank2,Child of Rank2 will be Rank3 like wise upto Rank6

Comment: you need a recursive way to add children to it's parent - take a look here and see what you can come up with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504110/recursive-call-return-a-list-return-type-causing-me-issues

Comment: Thanks for your input updated the question.Kindly look into it.